# Facebook LIKE plug in under fan page tabs

Tags: facebook

I am able to add the comment plugin under fan page tab but the LIKE plugin is not working..

But am sure this can be done as Samsung OMNIA did here

http://www.facebook.com/SamsungOmnia?v=app_201702137123&ref=ts

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating the tab as a Facebook Application instead of adding the FBML through StaticFBML tab. The LIKE button came automatically!